# Django-Braces - PermissionRequiredMixin redirecting to Login despite Permission being available

Tags: python, django, django-permissions, django-login

I am using django-braces MixIns.
I have set-up permissions for my user groups. and i have this Class Based View :

```
class ReportList(views.LoginRequiredMixin, views.PermissionRequiredMixin, ListView):
    permission_required = "auth.damage-report-list"
    model = DamageReport
    template_name = 'panel/reports.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    is_paginated = True

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ReportList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        for obj in context['object_list']:
            obj.alerts = DamageAlert.objects.filter(report__pk=obj.id)
        return context
```

As you can see i have added the LoginRequiredMixin and PermissionRequiredMixin. I also added a "Permission_required" field with the permission code name. I login as the user which has the required permission and i get redirected to a login screen. Any idea what could be going wrong here ?.

P.S : Is there anyway to redirect the user to a "Not authorized" page if he does not have the required permission ?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok my problem was an innocent one. for some reason i put auth. before the permission code instead of my app name which is panel

like this : "panel.damage-report-list"

Everything works. however i would still like to redirect to a special page when no authorization is available.